# What's causing the [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] error to be thrown? (Microsoft Login)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-ad-msal

I'm using Firebase to log into Microsoft in Flutter to be able to use the Graph API. I've run into an issue where the provided access token expires after an hour and the user needs to sign out and back in to be able to continue using functionality that requires the Graph API. After looking around, the suggested solution was to use a third-party oauth library like [azure_ad_authentication](https://pub.dev/packages/azure_ad_authentication) and then pass it into Firebase, which I've done like so

```dart
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
  return false;
}

final AzureAdAuthentication pca = await AzureAdAuthentication.createPublicClientApplication(
  clientId: clientId,
  authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
);

UserAdModel? userAdModel = await pca.acquireToken(scopes: [
  "openid",
  "Calendars.Read"
]);
if (userAdModel == null) {
  return false;
}

final credential = MicrosoftAuthProvider.credential(userAdModel.accessToken!);
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.linkWithCredential(credential);
```

I've verified that it returns an access token (and in the same format that Firebase itself uses when looking at the access token obtained from linking MicrosoftAuthProvider), but it throws the following error

```
E/flutter ( 7991): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed, has expired or is not currently supported.
E/flutter ( 7991): #0      FirebaseAuthUserHostApi.linkWithCredential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:1629:7)
E/flutter ( 7991): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7991): #1      MethodChannelUser.linkWithCredential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_user.dart:73:22)
E/flutter ( 7991): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7991): #2      User.linkWithCredential (package:firebase_auth/src/user.dart:190:9)
E/flutter ( 7991): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7991): #3      connectOutlookCalendar (package:xxxxx/providers/xxxxx.dart:74:3)
E/flutter ( 7991): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7991): #4      _MyPage.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:xxxxx/screens/xxxxx.dart:248:57)
E/flutter ( 7991): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7991):
```

As mentioned above, I've tried using a MicrosoftAuthProvider and even though it doesn't throw an error, it doesn't provide a way to refresh the token.

I expect it to pass without throwing an error, and link the currently signed-in account to the Microsoft account in Firebase. What happened was that it threw an error.